# Contact Form directly to email itself using php

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I tried many ways to solve this but seems like I hit the wall. It should be working with this way, but I couldnt find any mistake as it's written that there is a

> syntax error, unexpected $end

after I click submit button.

First of all, I type the code like this.

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="sendContact.php">  
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="contact-firstcol"> <label for="name">Name</label> </td>
                        <td class="contact-secondcol"> : </td>
                        <td class="contact-thirdcol"> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="contact-firstcol"> <label for="email">Email</label> </td>
                        <td class="contact-secondcol"> : </td>
                        <td class="contact-thirdcol"> <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="contact-firstcol"> <label for="phone">Phone</label> </td>
                        <td class="contact-secondcol"> : </td>
                        <td class="contact-thirdcol"> <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="contact-firstcol"> <label for="message">Message</label> </td>
                        <td class="contact-secondcol"> : </td>
                        <td class="contact-thirdcol"> <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="contact-firstcol"></td>
                        <td class="contact-secondcol"></td>
                        <td class="contact-thirdcol"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" /> </td>
                </table>    
            </form>
```

This file named sendContact.php

```
         <?php
            $to = 'abc@abc.com';
            $subject = 'from email contact';

            $name = $_POST ['name'];
            $email = $_POST ['email'];
            $phone = $_POST ['phone'];
            $message = $_POST ['message'];

            $body = <<< EMAIL
            Hi! My name is $name
            $message.
            From : $name
            Email : $email
            Topic : $topic
            EMAIL;
            $header = "From: $email";

            if (isset($_POST)) {
                if ($name == '' || $email == '' || $topic == '' || $message = '') {
                    $feedback = 'Please fill in any fields.';

                } else {

                mail( $to, $subject, $body, $header);
                $feedback = 'Thanks for the information, we will get back to you in 24 hours.';
                }
            }
?>
<p class="feedback"> <?php echo $feedback ?> </p>
```

I already make as simple as this and also make sure that the details on the email will be read easily. Can you point any mistakes above?

Cheers

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There cannot be any spaces between `<<<` and `EMAIL` in `<<< EMAIL`

It must be `<<<EMAIL` (see footnotes for more information)

**Consult:**

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

for more information on [`heredoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

**Example #1 Invalid example** (from the manual)

```
<?php
class foo {
    public $bar = <<<EOT
bar
    EOT;
}
?>
```

Example #2 Heredoc string quoting example

```
<?php
$str = <<<EOD
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.
EOD;

/* More complex example, with variables. */
class foo
{
    var $foo;
    var $bar;

    function foo()
    {
        $this->foo = 'Foo';
        $this->bar = array('Bar1', 'Bar2', 'Bar3');
    }
}

$foo = new foo();
$name = 'MyName';

echo <<<EOT
My name is "$name". I am printing some $foo->foo.
Now, I am printing some {$foo->bar[1]}.
This should print a capital 'A': \x41
EOT;
?>
```

Example #3 Heredoc in arguments example

```
<?php
var_dump(array(<<<EOD
foobar!
EOD
));
?>
```

---

**and in your case: (which I tested and working)**

I changed `$topic` to `$phone` otherwise it would have thrown an error.

You will need to further modify your PHP to reflect the appropriate changes.

```
<?php
$to = 'abc@abc.com';
$subject = 'from email contact';

$name = $_POST ['name'];
$email = $_POST ['email'];
$phone = $_POST ['phone'];
$message = $_POST ['message'];

$body = <<<EMAIL
Hi! My name is $name
$message.
From : $name
Email : $email
Topic : $topic
EMAIL;
$header = "From: $email";

if (isset($_POST)) {
    if ($name == '' || $email == '' || $phone == '' || $message = '') {
        $feedback = 'Please fill in any fields.';

    } else {

    mail( $to, $subject, $body, $header);
    $feedback = 'Thanks for the information, we will get back to you in 24 hours.';
    }
}
?>
<p class="feedback"> <?php echo $feedback ?> </p>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

And as Kostis stated in a comment --- *"It's the closing tag that must not have any whitespace in front. It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system."*

---

Comment: it is still not working too. I'm so confused what's wrong with this. And sometimes it is going to SPAM email. I don't understand why. Is there anything that I miss?

Comment: actually that's not true. It's the closing tag that must not have any whitespace in front " It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system" (from the link you provided)

Comment: @Anthosiastic Kostis made a point. There shouldn't be any space before your `EMAIL;` also. See my edit.

Comment: Note: You also need to change `$topic` to `$phone` otherwise it will throw an error. I will edit it in my answer now. @Anthosiastic I just tested it now and it worked ok.

Comment: However, you will need to further modify your PHP to reflect the changes. `$topic` was a stray variable. @Anthosiastic

Comment: Have you tried my code with "your" newly-formatted code? It works. @Anthosiastic And do read it in its entirety.

Comment: Ah, I see that you have. Glad it worked out and happy to have helped. @Anthosiastic Cheers

Comment: I didnt realise that $topic haven't changed and also didn't know about new line. The problem it is really working now. But until now I haven't received any in my own email. So weird. And thank you very much for spending your time to fix this problem. I'm really glad to meet you :)

Comment: Your ISP or Email provider may be blocking you, I've seen it happen before. Your code and `mail()` function are fine, as I stated that I tested it a few times and they all came into my INBOX without a hitch. Glad to make your acquaintance as well, Cheers. @Anthosiastic

Comment: Probably yeah. Since you've tested it and should be fine. Cheers @Fred-ii-